# issue with ant build

Tags: java, ant

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem in ant build invalid target release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956209/problem-in-ant-build-invalid-target-release)

Having issues building my project using ant with the following issue:

```
[echo] Using Java version 1.6.
build-java-lib:
make-jar:
clean:
   [delete] Deleting directory C:\xxx\bin
compile-src:
    [mkdir] Created dir: C:\xxx\bin
    [javac] Compiling 102 source files to C:\Users\xxx\Work\AndroidProjects\xxxx\bin
    [javac] javac: invalid target release: 1.6
    [javac] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
    [javac] where possible options include:
    [javac]   -g                         Generate all debugging info
    [javac]   -g:none                    Generate no debugging info
    [javac]   -g:{lines,vars,source}     Generate only some debugging info
    [javac]   -nowarn                    Generate no warnings
    [javac]   -verbose                   Output messages about what the compiler is doing
    [javac]   -deprecation               Output source locations where deprecated APIs are used
    [javac]   -classpath <path>          Specify where to find user class files
    [javac]   -cp <path>                 Specify where to find user class files
    [javac]   -sourcepath <path>         Specify where to find input source files
    [javac]   -bootclasspath <path>      Override location of bootstrap class files
    [javac]   -extdirs <dirs>            Override location of installed extensions
    [javac]   -endorseddirs <dirs>       Override location of endorsed standards path
    [javac]   -d <directory>             Specify where to place generated class files
    [javac]   -encoding <encoding>       Specify character encoding used by source files
    [javac]   -source <release>          Provide source compatibility with specified release
    [javac]   -target <release>          Generate class files for specific VM version
    [javac]   -version                   Version information
    [javac]   -help                      Print a synopsis of standard options
    [javac]   -X                         Print a synopsis of nonstandard options
    [javac]   -J<flag>                   Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system

BUILD FAILED
```

any suggestions?

Comment: Need a peek into your build.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a dup of [problem in ant build invalid target release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4956209/problem-in-ant-build-invalid-target-release) .  Make sure javac itself (not just Ant) is using Java 1.6.

Comment: how do i make sure javac is using Java1.6?

Comment: Sorry -- it was answered in the other SO question, so I didn't copy the answer.  Paraphrasing:  Read about javac task at http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html and use something like: <javac executable="/opt/java/jdk1.6/bin/javac" ... /> .